# MODX : Showing images using Migx and ImagePlus

Tags: image, modx-revolution

I am doing a project in Modx. I created a image slider using Migx. The client wants a image crop tool so I installed Image+.  In the `Form Tabs:` section of the migx variable, I  gave

```
[
{"caption":"Image", "fields":[
    {"field":"image","caption":"Image","inputTVtype":"imageplus"}
]}
]
```

and for `Grid Columns:`  I have given

```
[
{"header": "Image", "width": "50", "sortable": "false", "dataIndex": "image","renderer": "this.renderImagelus"}
]
```

In the grid column the selected images are not appearing (rest is working). I guess `"renderer": "this.renderImagelus"` is wrong, but I don't know what its value should be.
Can someone figure out a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

The current Image+ version from the MODX Repository could work with MIGX.

Use this in the `Form Tabs` section `"inputTVtype":"imageplus"` and this in `Grid Columns` section `"renderer": "ImagePlus.MIGX_Renderer`

If you want to use an own media source for the Image+ TV you have to add something like this in `Form Tabs` section just after the `inputTVtype` line

```
"sourceFrom": "migx",
"sources": [{
    "context": "web",
    "sourceid": "2"
}]
```